# How to loop through two separate files with one for loop and two variables in bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

```bsh
        for e in $(find .  -type f -name "*.sh")
        do

        done 
        cat code.log | while read k
        do
            chmod $k $e
        done
```

how do I combine the two loops 
one loop is finding all files with .sh extension and the other loop is looping through a file which has all the file permission octaves 
I want to combine the output of both the loops in a sequential order

for eg : file1.sh,file2.sh..

code.log =  777,666,665,556

I want the to chmod the file as per the permission

Comment: Why would this require 2 loops? Loop through code.log and then do a lookup of the file. What you do there is a cross section of both files.

Comment: (1) are the .sh files all in one directory, or do you really need to search for them recursively using `find`? (2) is the list of permissions really a single comma-separated line or is it one value per line?